# How do I customize default settings for new sites on wordpress multisite setup?

Tags: php, wordpress, multisite

I have set up Wordpress with a multisite network. I have been searching around for hours and can't seem to find much documentation on setting defaults for all the new sites that are created on my network.

Firstly I would like the default theme for all new sites created on the network to be my child-theme that is installed and Every new site starts with a default front page.

Secondly, Every new site must have a certain group of users (designers) assigned as admin

Should I try and create a mu-plugin if so please give some direction, or if there is a different way please advise.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make an mu-plugin to do anything complex with new sites within the network, but there is a selection is settings you can use to change the defaults on new networked sites from within the Network Admin.

See [Network Admin Settings Screen](https://codex.wordpress.org/Network_Admin_Settings_Screen).

If you're a Super Admin on the network, go to `Network Admin > Settings > Network Settings` where you can change these defaults.